# How to get Compiz wall desktop viewer to show more than 2 desktops?

Tags: kde, kubuntu, virtual-desktop, compiz

Since I've switched to KDE on my Ubuntu install (I guess for now I'm a Kubuntu guy) I can't see more than 2 of my virtual desktops in my Wall switcher. I can't even use the switcher to switch to the additional desktops, I have to select them with my mouse in the panel switcher.

How do I get Compiz working for all my KDE desktops just like I had with Gnome?

Comment: hm... after a little research I see I may should be just using the latest Kwin release instead of Compiz... but that is for another question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer:

remove Compiz. Use Kwin. All is well.

Comment: i strongly recommend going this way... kde software compilation are the most stable packages you'll see... compiz is always under regressions, bugging itself...

Answer (score 0):

install the compiz advanced desktop settings from the software center.